# iPhone opening content from webView in Safari

Tags: iphone, cocoa, uiwebview, webview

I have an iPhone application with some data and a small webView. Whenever user touches the webview it is supposed to open a Safari browser.

The problem is - when I close the opened Safari and start my application again it directly opens the full screen Safari. How can I prevent it?

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {   
    NSURL* url = [request URL];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
    return YES;
}
```

Before I was using the same code with `if (UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked == navigationType)` conditon but with that the 1st touch was opening inside my small webview instead of already in fullscreen browser.

Any idea how can I fix it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried returning `NO` from that delegate method?

Comment: nothing appears in my webview when I do that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to escape to the option of "application does not run in the background" in app-Info.plist file. It solves the issue of app starting with safari after coming back from background..

Answer (score 1):

Have you set a breakpoint in shouldStartLoadWithRequest: to see why it's being called again when the app is reopened? I'm surprised that it is.

You could set a flag in applicationDidEnterBackground when the app exits and check it in applicationDidEnterForeground and use that to guard the openURL request so that it's not called twice. That's a little messy though, I think you'd be better investigating what's calling shouldStartLoadWithRequest the second time.

Comment: Could be [self.webViewTwo loadHTMLString:myWebsiteCode baseURL:nil]; inside viewDidLoad...